# Font name in LuaTeX's fontspec

Tags: fonts, errors, luatex, fontspec

I have a document using `fontspec` which works fine with XeTeX, but a the Linux Libertine Initialis O font is not found when compiling with LuaTeX:

Here is a MWE reproducing the problem:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\lettrinefont{Linux Libertine Initials O}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

With `lualatex` (TL2011), it returns:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "LinuxLibertineInitialsO" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.7 ...ly\lettrinefont{Linux Libertine Initials O}
```

Here is the font in `fc-list`:

```
Linux Libertine Initials O:style=Initials
```

My `~/.texlive2011/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/otfl-names.lua` also contains an entry for this font:

```
  {
   ["familyname"]="Linux Libertine Initials O",
   ["filename"]={ "fxli.otf", false },
   ["fontname"]="LinLibertineIO",
   ["fullname"]="Linux Libertine Initials O",
   ["names"]={
    ["family"]="Linux Libertine Initials O",
    ["fullname"]="Linux Libertine Initials O",
    ["psname"]="LinLibertineIO",
    ["subfamily"]="Initials",
   },
   ["size"]={},
   ["slant"]=0,
   ["weight"]=400,
   ["width"]=5,
  },
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Well the font name is LinLibertineIO. So I tried `\newfontfamily\lettrinefont{LinLibertineIO}` and this works for me with lualatex. (It works with xelatex too but is slower than the other name.)

Comment: I eventually figured that out from reading `otfl-names.lua`, but how am I supposed to find that name with `fc-list`?

Comment: I think luaotfload fails to find it because of the `Initials` subfamily (naturally the code will be looking for `Regular` and its aliases). Using `LinLibertineIO` works because the code fallbacks to looking for `psname` as a last resort. It is messy code, but someone else have to fix it, I'm no longer interested in LaTeX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the name as specified in the `otfl-names.lua` works:

```
\newfontfamily\lettrinefont{LinLibertineIO}
```

However, I don't know why it worked for other fonts without using this name, and how I'm supposed to guess this name from the output of `fc-list`...

Comment: luaotfload does not use fontconfig for locating fonts, there is no guarantee the behaviour will always be the same.